# How correctly perform a query that JOIN 2 tables using 2 differents fields that are into these tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I am pretty new in SQL and I have the following problem with a simple query.

I have to perform a query that **JOIN** 2 tables. The join operation is not on a single field but have to be performed on 2 differents field having the same name on these tables.

So I have done something like this:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM TID003_ANAGEDIFICIO anagraficaEdificio 
INNER JOIN TID002_CANDIDATURA candidatura ON(candidatura.PRG_PAR = anagraficaEdificio.PRG_PAR, candidatura.PRG_CAN = anagraficaEdificio.PRG_CAN)
WHERE anagraficaEdificio.FLG_GRA=1;
```

But, performing this query, I obaint the following error message:

> **Operand should contain 1 column(s)**

As you can see I am trying to join these 2 tables and the join is based on 2 fields, by:

```
ON(candidatura.PRG_PAR = anagraficaEdificio.PRG_PAR, candidatura.PRG_CAN = anagraficaEdificio.PRG_CAN)
```

What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AND` to specify the additional join conditions if you want to use more than one condition together:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM TID003_ANAGEDIFICIO anagraficaEdificio 
JOIN TID002_CANDIDATURA candidatura 
  ON candidatura.PRG_PAR = anagraficaEdificio.PRG_PAR 
 AND candidatura.PRG_CAN = anagraficaEdificio.PRG_CAN
WHERE anagraficaEdificio.FLG_GRA = 1;
```

If the column names of the joined columns are the same in both tables you could use a join with the `USING` predicate instead:

```
JOIN TID002_CANDIDATURA candidatura USING (PRG_PAR, PRG_CAN)
```

This is not supported in all databases, but it is in MySQL (see the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) for more information).